# TrueType font not displaying as expected in some desktop applications

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gimp, truetype-fonts

So I have a TTF of the font "Woodcut" ([you can get it here](https://zerm.chrissx.ga/Woodcut.ttf)) and it works completely fine in HTML and SVGs, as you can see below.

But when I try to view it in Gnome [Font Viewer](https://help.gnome.org/misc/release-notes/3.6/users-font-viewer.html.uk), it just shows black boxes. And in Gimp it just looks like Arial. (there its name is shown as being "Woodcut weight=101")

What is wrong with this TTF that it breaks there and what I can do to fix this?

[image: Woodcut Font]

Comment: In GIMP its name shows up incorrectly as "Woodcut weight=101" (besides not working). Maybe that is clue to where it is broken?

Comment: @jsbueno forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

**update** Meh - forget it, reading on the specs, it is *normal* for the checksum for the head table to be *broken* (go figure), as one of its fields contain the checksum for the whole fontfile, and thus it would not be possible to compute both the "head table" checksum and the whole file checksum and have both correct. In other words, I've found *nothing* yet.

**previously**

Playing around with the [TTF specs](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/) and some Python interactive shell, I could find out the checksum for the "head table" inside this file is broken.

That is it for now - I am still fooling around to try to fix it. 
I don't think my Python snippets are relevant for the answer, but I could post them. The checksum result I got for the tables in the font is:

```
[(b'OS/2', True), (b'cmap', True), (b'cvt ', True), (b'fpgm', True), (b'glyf', True), (b'hdmx', True), (b'head', False), (b'hhea', True), (b'hmtx', True), (b'loca', True), (b'maxp', True), (b'name', True), (b'post', True), (b'prep', True)]
```